# Combine multiple DataFrames with occasional overlaps

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have multiple sub-DataFrames which I read from CSV files, and I want to combine them to one big DataFrame using `pandas`.

My issue is that some of the columns in the separate sub-DataFrames show an overlap. And if they do, the values need to be inserted at the correct place in the final DataFrame.

Generally, all sub-DataFrames have an `ID` column - the `set` of all `ID` values of all those DataFrames, should combine to the final big DataFrame's `ID` column.

Each `ID` has a specific `CODE` assigned to it, which is consistent among all sub-DataFrames, so it could potentially be always overwritten as the values should remain the same.

I've tried every-which way, `merge`, `join`, `concat` and even plain old loop and index, with index column, without, you name it - but, to no avail.

I want to add, that some methods create new columns with suffixes - but my intention is to combine all values from overlapping columns into a single column, so that is not an option/

Here's some sample data:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(42)

df_1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'ID':[3,4,5,6],
    'CODE':[2,2,5,4],
    'M1':np.random.rand(4),
    'M2':np.random.rand(4)    
})

df_2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'ID':[8,9,10],
    'CODE':[7,2,4],
    'M1':np.random.rand(3),
    'M2':np.random.rand(3)    
})


df_3 = pd.DataFrame({
    'ID':[3,4,5,6],
    'CODE':[2,2,5,4],
    'M3':np.random.rand(4),
    'M4':np.random.rand(4)    
})

df_4 = pd.DataFrame({
    'ID':[8,9,10],
    'CODE':[7,2,4],
    'M3':np.random.rand(3),
    'M4':np.random.rand(3)    
})

df_5 = pd.DataFrame({
    'ID':[8,9,10],
    'CODE':[7,2,4],
    'M5':np.random.rand(3),
    'M6':np.random.rand(3)    
})
```

Using `merge` with `how="outer"` I was able to merge `df_1`, `df_2` and `df_3` with the result being as I need it.

```
ID  CODE    M1  M2  M3  M4
0   3   2   0.374540    0.156019    0.181825    0.431945
1   4   2   0.950714    0.155995    0.183405    0.291229
2   5   5   0.731994    0.058084    0.304242    0.611853
3   6   4   0.598658    0.866176    0.524756    0.139494
4   8   7   0.601115    0.969910    NaN         NaN
5   9   2   0.708073    0.832443    NaN         NaN
6   10  4   0.020584    0.212339    NaN         NaN
```

But adding `df_4`, the data gets appended below rather then inserted in the correct places (so there would be no `NaN`s in this case):

```
    ID  CODE      M1          M2          M3          M4
0   3   2   0.374540    0.156019    0.181825    0.431945
1   4   2   0.950714    0.155995    0.183405    0.291229
2   5   5   0.731994    0.058084    0.304242    0.611853
3   6   4   0.598658    0.866176    0.524756    0.139494
4   8   7   0.601115    0.969910    NaN         NaN
5   9   2   0.708073    0.832443    NaN         NaN
6   10  4   0.020584    0.212339    NaN         NaN
7   8   7   NaN         NaN        0.292145     0.785176
8   9   2   NaN         NaN        0.366362     0.199674
9   10  4   NaN         NaN        0.456070     0.514234
```

Finally, combining all DataFrames in this example should yield this result:

```
    ID  CODE      M1          M2          M3          M4     M5         M6
0   3   2   0.374540    0.156019    0.181825    0.431945    NaN         NaN
1   4   2   0.950714    0.155995    0.183405    0.291229    NaN         NaN
2   5   5   0.731994    0.058084    0.304242    0.611853    NaN         NaN
3   6   4   0.598658    0.866176    0.524756    0.139494    NaN         NaN
4   8   7   0.601115    0.969910    0.292145    0.785176    0.592414    0.170524
5   9   2   0.708073    0.832443    0.366362    0.199674    0.046450    0.065051
6   10  4   0.020584    0.212339    0.456070    0.514234    0.607544    0.948885
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Merge dataframes with identical ID and codes and concatenate them.

```
pd.concat([df_1.merge(df_3, how = 'outer'),df_2.merge(df_4, how = 'outer').merge(df_5, how = 'outer')], sort = True)

    ID  CODE    M1      M2          M3          M4          M5          M6
0   3   2   0.374540    0.156019    0.181825    0.431945    NaN         NaN
1   4   2   0.950714    0.155995    0.183405    0.291229    NaN         NaN
2   5   5   0.731994    0.058084    0.304242    0.611853    NaN         NaN
3   6   4   0.598658    0.866176    0.524756    0.139494    NaN         NaN
4   8   7   0.601115    0.969910    0.292145    0.785176    0.592415    0.170524
5   9   2   0.708073    0.832443    0.366362    0.199674    0.046450    0.065052
6   10  4   0.020584    0.212339    0.456070    0.514234    0.607545    0.948886
```

Another solution using groupby. Concat all dataframes on axis 0, groupby on ID, CODE and first() returns first non-NaN value.

```
dfs = [df_1, df_2, df_3, df_4, df_5]

pd.concat(dfs, sort = False).groupby(['CODE', 'ID']).first().sort_index(level = 1).reset_index()
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Looks like a working solution for the testdata. However, with the real csv files, I can't know apriori which dataframes will have matching IDs/codes since they are read one at a time from disk.

Comment: How many csv files? May be you can run separate check first. Something like; set(df_1.ID) == set(df_2.ID).  Merge only those where IDs are common, concat later.

Comment: 33 files with anything from 3000 to 30000 rows. But I was looking for a more general solution given `pandas`' plentiful functionalities. But I assume your approach would be working, I just need to iterate the files multiple times, which I would like to avoid. My first idea was to create an empty dataframe with a set of all IDs, and then add the data as it comes in ... however I didn't manage to realize this idea.

Comment: In pandas, all your columns need to be of same length and hence it introduces NaN whenever it doesn't find relevant data. Which is the issue when you merge 1,2 and 3. While merging 4; the rows are added below existing data rather than filling missing values. Combination of merge and concat seem to be the most optimal solution

Comment: I see no issue on how pandas behaves with merging df 1-3. But given the fact that when merging 4, I have matching ID/CODE values and also matching column names, isn't there a force overwrite or similar?

Comment: Pl see the edit, the groupby solution might work for large number of files